# Firebird and Table,field name lowercase

Tags: firebird

I have converted a database from MySQL to Firebird, all tables name and field name are in lowercase, when I query the database, it gives me an error of table not found, because Firebird automatically converted the name of table in the query in UPPERCASE letters, but my table name in database is lowercase.

To query the database, I'm required to enclose the name of the table or the name of the field in double quotes, for example:

```
SELECT "field1","field2" FROM "table"
```

Is there a setting in Firebird to allow to query database with table/field name in lowercase letter without quoting it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. BTW, I suggest you to always create DB objects in uppercase (and without double quotes) in Firebird. This simplifies a lot, since you can access them writing in any case (even mixed case).